# (Chess) Problem with negamax search missing checkmate

Tags: c++, chess, minimax, negamax

I'm implementing a search algorithm into the search function with *Negamax* with *alpha-beta pruning*. However, it often misses forced checkmate.
(**Note:** "Mate in X" counts whole turns, while "depth" and "move(s)" relies on half moves.)

## Example

The position with the following FEN: `1k1r4/pp1b1R2/3q2pp/4p3/2B5/4Q3/PPP2B2/2K5 b - - 0 1` has a Mate in 3 (depth of 5 to the algorithm).
It goes Qd1+, Kxd1, Bg4+, Kc1/Ke1 (Doesn't matter), Rd1#.

It can spot the checkmate from 1 move away, but fails at higher depths.

## Possible Causes

It could be a typo, a misused `type`, or even a complete misunderstanding of the method, as all of it happened before.

## Simplified Code

I've make some part of the code code easier to read. (eg. remove `std::`, turns multiple lines into function).
Shouldn't changes the functionalities though.

### Root Call

```
pieceMove searchBestMove (gameState currentState, int depth) {
//Calls the Negamax search
    pieceColor sideToMove = whoseTurnIsIt();
    
    vector<pieceMove> moveList = generateLegalMoves(currentState, sideToMove);
    
    pieceMove bestMove;
    signed int bestEval = numeric_limits<signed int>::max();
    
    for (const auto move : moveList) {
        signed int evaluation = negaMax(applyMove(currentState, move), numeric_limits<signed int>::min(), numeric_limits<signed int>::max(), depth - 1, 1);
        if (evaluation < bestEval) {
            bestMove = move;
            bestEval = evaluation;
        }
    }
    
    return bestMove;
}
```

### Search Function

```
signed int negaMax (gameState currentState, signed int alpha, signed int beta, int depth, int rootDepth) {
//Main Negamax search
    //Terminal node
    if (depth == 0) {
        return evaluates(currentState); //Replace this line with the one below to enable the extended search
        //return quiescenceSearch(currentState, alpha, beta); 
    }
    
    //Mate distance pruning
    signed int mateDistScore = numeric_limits<signed int>::max() - rootDepth;
    alpha = max(alpha, -mateDistScore);
    beta = min(beta, mateDistScore - 1);
    if (alpha >= beta) return alpha;
    
    vector<pieceMove> moveList = generateLegalMoves(currentState);

    //If no moves are allowed, then it's either checkmate or stalemate
    if (moveList.size() == 0) return evaluates(currentState)
     
    orderMoves(currentState, moveList);


    for (const auto move : moveList) {
        signed int score = -negaMax(applyMove(currentState, move), -beta, -alpha, depth - 1, rootDepth + 1);
        if (score >= beta) return beta; //Bata cutoff
        alpha = max(score, alpha);
    }
    
    return alpha;
}
```

### Extended Search

```
signed int quiescenceSearch (gameState currentState, signed int alpha, signed int beta) {
//Searches only captures
    //Terminal node
    int evaluation = evaluates(currentState);
    if (evaluation >= beta) return beta;
    alpha = max(alpha, evaluation);
    
    vector<pieceMove> moveList = generateCaptureMoves(currentState);

    //If no moves are allowed, then it's either checkmate or stalemate
    if (moveList.size() == 0) return evaluates(currentState);
    
    orderMoves(currentState, moveList);

    for (const auto move : moveList) {
        signed int score = -quiescenceSearch(applyMove(currentState, move), -beta, -alpha);
        if (score >= beta) return beta; //Bata cutoff
        alpha = max(score, alpha);
    }
    
    return alpha;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to call the function "quiescenceSearch" when the depth is 0 in "negaMax". Also you need to check for "checks" too in "quiescenceSearch" along with captures since they are not quiet moves. Also Matedistance pruning works only when positions are properly scored(https://www.chessprogramming.org/Mate_Distance_Pruning#Mating_Value). May be checking if your evaluation function is evaluating properly could also help.

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly the answer - the evaluation if black wins is `numeric_limit::min()`, and when the algorithm tries to be black-centric with the evaluation (which Negamax requires), it tries to multiply it with `-1`, and yields `numeric_limit::max() + 1` which caused an overflow.